# Sampling the rows randomly by the specific rules in R

Tags: r, random, sample, group

I have `dat1` and `dat2` like this:

```
dat1<-data.frame(company=c("a","b","c"),
                 random=c(2,1,1),
                 prior=c(1,3,1))

dat2<-data.frame(company=c("a","a",'a',"b","b","a","a","c","c","c",
                           "b","b","b"),
                 peter=c(5,0,1,1,1,0,100,7,8,7,0,0,1),
                 turner=c(5,1,2,1,2,0,200,7,9,6,0,0,0),
                 austin=c(7,5,3,1,0,0,300,77,10,5,0,1,1),
                 label=c("random","random","prior","random","random","random","prior",
                         "random","random","prior","prior","prior","prior"))
```

`dat2` is the original data and `dat1` gives the guidline how to pick sample rows from `dat2`. For example, if you look at the `dat1` , for `company`==`a`, `random`=2 and `prior`=1. It means that you have to find `company`==a in `dat2` and pick 2 rows randomly form `company`==`a`  with `label`==`random`. Also, you have to find `company`==`a` in `dat2` and pick 1 row from `company`==`a` with `label`==`prior` . So the possible extracted sampled rows data should look like this:

```
data<-data.frame(company=c("a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c"),
                 peter=c(5,0,100,1,0,0,1,7,7),
                 turner=c(5,1,200,1,0,0,0,7,6),
                 austin=c(7,5,300,1,0,1,1,77,5),
                 label=c("random","random","prior","random","prior","prior","prior","random","prior"))
```

So my question is how to get `data` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data <- data.frame()

for (i in seq(nrow(dat1))) {
    data <- rbind(
        data,
        dat2 |>
            filter(company == dat1[i, 1], label == "random") |>
            slice_sample(n = dat1[i, 2]),
        dat2 |>
            filter(company == dat1[i, 1], label == "prior") |>
            slice_sample(n = dat1[i, 3])
    )
}

> data
  company peter turner austin  label
1       a     0      0      0 random
2       a     0      1      5 random
3       a     1      2      3  prior
4       b     1      1      1 random
5       b     0      0      1  prior
6       b     1      0      1  prior
7       b     0      0      0  prior
8       c     7      7     77 random
9       c     7      6      5  prior
```